# PHP : Getting Data From An Array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a set of data that looks like this

```
 { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (19) { ["text"]=> string(39) "So true! :(" } object(stdClass)#5 (19) { ["text"]=> string(39) "Some other text"}
```

I tried this but it's not returning any data

```
$content->{0}->text;  
$content->{1}->text;
```

how to get this data? it's not returning any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are objects inside array, you can access them like this:

```
$content[0]->text
```